# Form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

i would like to create page, that handle data from user and create instance of my Employee class. I created form acording to tutorial on the internet, but when i run application, i get error posted below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

Code of form is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Employee add</h1>
<form:form method="POST" action="/employee/add">
   <table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td></tr></table>
  </form:form>
</body></html>
```

EmployeeController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/employee"})
public class EmployeeController {

@RequestMapping(value = {"/employeeForm"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String employeePage() {
    System.out.println("EmployeeController");
    return "/employee/add";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("ProjectSpring") Employee employee,
        ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", employee.getFirstName());
    model.addAttribute("age", employee.getLastName());

    return "index";
}   
}
```

Can anyone tell me, what cause this error, please??

Comment: You need to show us your controller that is handling the POST from this form.

Comment: Where is your model attribute `"ProjectSpring"` being defined?

Answer (score 1):

First add the 'commandName' attribute to the form tag and its value is bean name which is added in ModelMap as attribute like below :

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="ProjectSpring" action="/employee/add">
```

Please add the bean instance in ModelMap in the controller so it can be available in jsp. ie:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/employeeForm"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String employeePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("ProjectSpring", new Employee ());
    System.out.println("EmployeeController");
    return "index";
}
```

Now your code will work... enjoy...